# Spreadsheet styling every X rows

Tags: google-spreadsheets

In **Google Spreadsheet**, how can I change the background color at **every X rows**.
For example, Let say I need every fifth row to be in gray background, I can I achieve this?

I already know how to do alternate with `=ISEVEN(ROW())` , but how can I achieve a similar result with X rows?

Comment: Does `=MOD(ROW(),X)=0` work? This should equal true if row is a multiple of X.

Comment: Websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress are off topic, See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://webapps.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @NonlinearFruit nope, the rule doesn't validate (display in red).